# FreeNAS CIFS/Samba shares visible but not accessible

Tags: samba, freenas, cifs

I have a FreeNAS 9.3 server and am trying to configure the following Samba shares:

1. A share called 'public' accessible to all authenticated users
2. A home directory share, visible only to the corresponding user

I set up both shares, the second one with "Use as home share" checked. The NAS is set to the same workgroup as my Windows PC and I created a user with the same name (e.g. Abcd) and password on the NAS.

Both the 'public' and user share ('Abcd') are displayed in the Windows Explorer, however

1. If I try to access the public share, I get an access denied error
2. If I try to access the Abcd share, I get a path not found error

How can I solve these issues?

**Updates:**

I "solved" the path not found error, however, now I get access denied errors for *both* directories. I was seeing the following error:

```
canonicalize_connect_path failed for service Abcd, path /mnt/zroot/home/abcd
```

The unix username is in fact "Abcd" *not* "abcd" so there is no such directory. Creating a symlink from abcd to Abcd "solves" this issue. What is the correct solution?

**Answers to Comments:**

The output of `net view <ip>` is:

```
Shared resources at <ip>

FreeNAS Server

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abcd        Disk           Home Directories
public      Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

For public `net use *` succeeds with

```
Drive Z: is now connected to \\<ip>\public.

The command completed successfully.
```

`net view` however fails with

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

For Abcd `net use *` fails with

```
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

and `net view` fails with

```
System error 1707 has occurred.

The network address is invalid.
```

Comment: From windows in cmd.exe: what is the result of `net view \\<ip of the nas>`?

Comment: @boboes info added to question

Comment: What is the result of `net use * \\<ip>\Abcd` and `net use * \\<ip>\public`? If you get an drive letter assigned (like Z:), what happens when you access the nas through the letter? (Typing Z: in cmd.exe)

Comment: @boboes more info added. so far everything is consistent with the behavior of Explorer

Comment: Is the `TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service` running on Windows? Is the workgroup name in samba an Windows written exactly same (including lower/uppercase)?

Comment: @boboes yes to both questions